# Zend Equivalent to Update Case

Tags: zend-framework, mysql

I am looking to create a query similar to the below using the Zend Framework.

```
  UPDATE table
   SET column = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'value 3'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'value 9'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'value 1'
   END
  WHERE id IN (1,2,7)
```

What is the 'Zend Way' of doing Case Updates?

As a work around I am using Zend_DB_Expr but would prefer to not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is none.**

[Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) is the way to go if you want to use CASE statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build the case with Zend_Db_Expr [Zend_db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html)

You can look [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/SQL-Case-statement-in-Zend-Framework-td656393.html) for an similar example